# Stringify json object in array, that is equal to date

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I would like to tell a json object, to stringify the object that belongs to the array with this days date/time.

I have a php script which fetches a json object, with multiple arrays in it, which looks something like this:

```
data: Array(55)

    0: {date: "2017112700", p: Array(1)}
    1: {date: "2017112701", p: Array(1)}
    2: {date: "2017112702", p: Array(1)}

    and so forth...55 in all.
```

I am able to verify that my date variable (date_test) matches a date variable in the json array.

```
var date_test;

var index = json.data.findIndex(function(item, i){
  return item.date === date_test
});

console.log(index);
```

Lets say that `console.log(index);` gives my a '9'.

This shows me where `date_test` and `item.date` match.

Now this where I am stuck....I can stringify and whatever the information from the json arrays, but I would like stringify the object that matches my date_test. Anyone?

Comment: Why not JSON.parse it and find the actual data?

Comment: Do you want the complete object of which date matches?

Comment: The returned data does not look like JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the object that machtes your search:

```
var obj = json.data[index]; //your previously found index
```

Then stringify it:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: in case you just need to stringify the p array use this to grab it:
`json.data[index].p`

Comment: This was it! Thanks...the simple answer! I just used for example: var json_temp = JSON.stringify(json.data[index].p[0]["temperature"]); and then console.log(json_temp);

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`Array#find()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** like this:

```
let date_test = "2017112701";

var searchObj = arr.find(function(item) {
  return item.date === date_test;
});
```

Then you can stringify it:

```
JSON.stringify(searchObj);
```

**Demo:**

```js
var arr = [{
    date: "2017112700",
    p: []
  },
  {
    date: "2017112701",
    p: []
  },
  {
    date: "2017112702",
    p: []
  }
];

let date_test = "2017112701";

var searchObj = arr.find(function(item) {
  return item.date === date_test;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(searchObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.grep()` to filter the json data as shown below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myObj = [{
      date: "2017112700",
      p: ['a']
    },
    {
      date: "2017112701",
      p: ['b']
    },
    {
      date: "2017112702",
      p: ['c']
    }
  ];
  var mydate = '2017112701';
  var output = $.grep(myObj, function(value, index) {
    return value.date == mydate;
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

var json_temp = JSON.stringify(json.data[index].p[0]["temperature"]); and then console.log(json_temp);